# Upload coverage information to SonarCloud from coverlet for C# project

Tags: yaml, github-actions, coverlet, dotnet-test

I'm trying to collect coverage info and publish it to SonarCloud for my C# project, using GitHub Actions as my CI pipeline. The execution is very simple, basically trying to execute tests for all projects, merging all coverage files:

```
run: |
  .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"LanguageDev_Yoakke" /o:"languagedev" /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="CoverageResults/coverage.opencover.xml" /d:"sonar.verbose=true"
  dotnet build
  dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput="../CoverageResults/" /p:MergeWith="../CoverageResults/coverage.json" /p:CoverletOutputFormat=\"opencover,json\" /maxcpucount:1
  .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}"
```

Note, that I do need to output in both `opencover` and `json` formats. `coverlet` only seems to merge properly is `json` is among the output formats, so it can then convert that to `opencover` in the end.

The problem is, this generates no coverage information on the CI - downloading artifacts show no generated folder or files. However, if just pass `/p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover`, all coverage information is generated on the CI - but not merged properly because of no `json` output.

Locally, the command

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput="../CoverageResults/" /p:MergeWith="../CoverageResults/coverage.json" /p:CoverletOutputFormat=\"opencover,json\" /maxcpucount:1
```

just works and generates the proper coverage XML file.

What could be the problem, why does it not work with both coverage formats specified for the CI? Initially I thought that I do not know about escaping quotes in YAML but this does not seem to be the case here.